# Flask sending EventStreams to HTML and JS getting Event messages

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask

I have built a code that sends GEO data into Kafka system that is then being picked up in Flask application and streamed into seperate page. I want that live stream that is being updated every seconds to be pickedup by javascript and place point of geo on the map. When I run the script it seems that it identifies the eventsource but when I want to print out the live data it does not find any live data.

```js
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
    
L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
    tileSize: 512,
    zoomOffset: -1,
    accessToken: '[redacted]'
}).addTo(mymap);
    
var source = new EventSource('/topic/London');
source.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(e.data);
    console.log(obj);
}, false);
```

Here is the screenshot of data being streamed every second:
[image]

But it is not being returned to console by JavaScript
[image]

I have tried to debug the code by adding some additional code on seeing what events are being triggered. When code runs it shows me that connection is 'Open' and EventState.readyState is 1 meaning its OPEN:

```
ssEvent = new EventSource( '/topic/London' );
ssEvent.onopen = function (evt) {
  console.log('Open');
}
ssEvent.onerror = function (evt) {
  console.log('Error');
}
ssEvent.onmessage = function (evt) {
  console.log('Message');
}
```

[image]

Here is my Flask app code:

```
  from flask import Flask
  from flask import render_template
  from flask import Response
  from pykafka import KafkaClient

  app = Flask(__name__)

  def kafkaClient():
      return KafkaClient(hosts = 'localhost:9092')

  @app.route('/')
  def index():
      return render_template('index.html')


  @app.route('/topic/<topicname>')
    def get_message(topicname):
      client = kafkaClient()
      def events():
          for i in client.topics[topicname].get_simple_consumer():
              yield 'data{0}\n\n'.format(i.value.decode())
      return Response(events(), mimetype= 'text/event-stream')

  if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True, port = 5001)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by going into App.py file and adding into function that uses yield and added events name and data that I want to stream.

Updated Flask App looks like:

```
 @app.route('/topic/<topicname>', methods=['GET'])
def get_message(topicname):
    client = kafkaClient()
    def events():
        for i in client.topics[topicname].get_simple_consumer():
            yield "event: {0}\ndata: {1}\n\n".format("listen", i.value.decode())
    return Response(events(), mimetype= 'text/event-stream')
```